# What evidence was there in "The Naked Sun" to suggest that Baley had feelings for Gladia?

Tags: isaac-asimov, the-naked-sun

I just finished reading *The Robots of Dawn*, and was quite surprised firstly when Elijah Baley was excited that he'd visit the world Gladia was on, and secondly when at the end of the novel he calls her "my love".

> His lips shaped: *Good-bye*. And then because there was no sound -  he could not have done it with sound - he added, *my love*.
>   And her lips moved, too. *Good-bye, my dearest love*.

I may have flipped the few more sentimental pages of *The Naked Sun* rather fast, but I don't recall Baley showing that he had any newborn feelings of romantic sort towards Gladia. It appeared to me that Baley merely acknowledged her beauty, but nothing more.

Am I wrong? Were there actually passages that suggested he was falling in love with, or otherwise attracted to Gladia?

Comment: It's been decades since I read that novel. Asimov used to include excruciatingly prissy love/sex scenes in his stories, presumably to appeal to adolescent boys (they would be laughed at now), so I wouldn't be surprised if there was some love interest, however pointless. Now, a relationship between R. Daneel and Gladia would have been really shocking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes.

We see several times that he considered her attractive:

> She lifted her arms above her head, running her fingers through the hair and spreading it out as though to hasten drying. Her arms were slim and graceful. Very attractive, Baley thought.
>
> <sub>Chapter 4</sub>

...

> She looked up, her face as pretty as ever, despite its obvious distress -  perhaps because of it.
>
> <sub>Chapter 5</sub>

We then start to see signs that he is beginning to fall in love with her:

> Or was it Gladia? He would be seeing her soon, not viewing her. Was that what gave him confidence and this odd feeling of mixed apprehension and anticipation?
>    <sub>Chapter 15</sub>

...

> "Are you perhaps being influenced by extraneous motives of your own, Partner Elijah? Mrs. Delmarre is an attractive woman and you are an Earthman in whom a preference for the personal presence of an attractive woman is not psychotic."
>   "I have better reasons," said Baley uneasily. (Daneel's cool glance was too penetrating and soul-dissecting by half. Jehoshaphat! The thing was only a machine.)
>
> <sub>Chapter 16</sub>

And now, towards the end, there is this quote, which is possibly the most telling.

> "You will." Baley looked at the slim girl who stood before him and said, **not without a momentary pang**, "And you will be married someday, too. Really married, I mean."
>
> <sub>Chapter 18</sub>

...

> Even the thought that a ship was waiting to take him back to Earth **did not wipe out the sense of loss he felt at that moment**.
>
> Undersecretary Albert Minnim's look was intended to be one of prim welcome. "I am glad to see you back on Earth. Your report, of course, arrived before you did and is being studied. You did a good job. The matter will look well in your record."
>   "Thank you," said Baley. There was no room for further elation in him. Being back on Earth; being safe in the Caves; **being in hearing of Jessie's voice (he had spoken to her already) had left him strangely empty**.
>
> <sub>Chapter 18</sub>